# Passing an array to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, subroutine

When I pass an array to a subroutine, does it shift the whole array or just an pointer to the memory path?
My problem looks like:

```
program run
   real,dimension :: p(200,200,200)
   integer :: i

   do i=0,10000000
      call sub_p(p)
   enddo
end

subroutine sub_p(rhs)
   real,dimension :: rhs(200,200,200)

   ...

end
```

Becuase if the whole array is passed it probably takes longer regarding runtime?

@Vladimir:
So in the code above a pointer is passed but if the code looks like the following the array is copied?:

```
program run
   real,dimension :: p(200,200,200)
   integer,parameter :: imax = 198
   integer,parameter :: jmax = 198
   integer,parameter :: kmax = 198
   integer :: ib,ie,jb,je,kb,ke
   integer :: i

   ib=1; ie=ib+imax
   jb=1; je=jb+jmax
   kb=1; ke=kb+kmax

   do i=0,10000000
      call sub_p(p(ib:ie,jb:je,kb:ke))
   enddo
end

subroutine sub_p(rhs)
   integer,parameter :: imax = 198
   integer,parameter :: jmax = 198
   integer,parameter :: kmax = 198
   real,dimension :: rhs(imax,jmax,kmax)

   ...

end
```

Am I right?

Comment: This depends in part on how the subroutine is defined.  [For example, whether the dummy argument has the `value` attribute.]

Comment: @francescalus The code is written in F90 standard is there even a value option?

Comment: Not in f90 or 95, but has been since 2003

Comment: There's no standard one that early, but compilers often have directives and the like.

Comment: @IanBush so than it mean that in my code the whole array is passed? I need an `interface` to use the `value` option don't I? Is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What is currently occurring the the code your have written? If you haven't written anything why don't you try it? What do you want to happen? I have to say the above all looks fine to me, but I probably don't understand what you want.

Comment: @IanBush I already have a code which looks like the example given in the question above! I'm now worried that the passing of the array is very time consuming if the whole array is passed to the subroutine. I added a loop to the example to make I more understandable!

Comment: I guess instead of `subroutine sub_p(rhs)`, you must have `subroutine sub_p(p)`, or define `rhs` for your question to be answered.

Comment: @innoSPG your completly right .... i fixed it!

Comment: By default, fortran passes arguments by reference. So in your case, there is no copy.

Comment: @innoSPG Thanks! Perfect I hoped that!

Comment: @chi86 You can confirm whether a copy is created or not by attaching an option like  -fcheck-array-temporaries or -fcheck=array-temps (for gfortran). I guess there will be similar options for ifort too.

Comment: @roygvib That's an nice feature! Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the interface is implicit or the dummy argument is an explicit shape array, as you have, a pointer is passed. (The standard doesn't say that explicitly, but effectively it is the only possible implementation.

But it can be a pointer to a copy! If the array is not contiguous and the interface is implicit there will be a copy!

In your case:

no copy:

```
call sub_p(p)
```

a copy required:

```
call similar_sub(p(1,:,:))
```

Comment: Ok that I understand. I added another example to my question would you look at it?

Comment: Yes, the other example requires a copy.